# How to use uppercaseString, lowercaseString in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string

I have `Strings` and I want to convert to `uppercaseString`, `lowercaseString` with `only letters`.

My strings;

```
let uppers  = " Hello*im ; + Upper+String "
let lowers  = " Hello*im ; + Lower+String "
print(uppers)
print(lowers)
```

**Output of upper case looks like this**

```
HELLOIMUPPERSTRING
```

Thank you !

Comment: what do you mean with "only letters"?

Comment: @ddb delete  ; * + characters also

Comment: so uppers should become "HELLOIMUPPERSTRING", isn't it?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but I don't get this at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Set` for that.

```
let uppers  = " Hello*im ; + Upper+String "
let lowers  = " Hello*im ; + Lower+String "
let allowChars : Set<Character> = Set("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890".characters)
let upperStr = String(uppers.characters.filter {allowChars.contains($0) }).uppercaseString
let lowerStr = String(lowers.characters.filter {allowChars.contains($0) }).lowercaseString
print(upperStr)
print(lowerStr)
```

**Edit:** To allow space also add space inside the `Set` characters with other character

```
let allowChars : Set<Character> = Set("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890".characters)
```

Comment: I have edited the `Character` `Set` as of you doesn't want `space` also so i have removed the space from the set.

Comment: Thanks please add with space also

Comment: Just add space inside that `""` of set characters string.

Answer (score 1):

First strip your Strings from non-alphanumeric characters, then convert to lowercase or uppercase.

```
let charactersToRemove = NSCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet().invertedSet
let strippedReplacement = " ".join(myString.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(charactersToRemove))
let resultUppercase = strippedReplacement.uppercaseString
let resultLowercase = strippedReplacement.lowercaseString
```